# Counting values in a row that match a condition - Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, count

I have a dataframe that contains integers and NaNs. I am almost looking to create a countif statement, which will iterate over each value in a row and count values that are greater than 0.

Here is an example df:

```
d = {'col1': [1, "", 5, 0], 'col2': [3, 4, "", 7], 'col3': [2, 8, "", 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)

df
Out[356]: 
col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   3.0   2.0
1   NaN   4.0   8.0
2   5.0   NaN   NaN
3   0.0   7.0   3.0
```

I have been using this function below that counts values that are not NaNs, however I want to place a condition on this (greater than 0 & not NaN).

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis = 1)
Out[357]: 
0    3
1    2
2    1
3    3
dtype: int64
```

If anyone could offer advice on how to count values in a row based on a certain condition that would be very useful, thanks in advance.

Comment: `(df > 0).sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: You have `3` for your last row, but there are only two entries in the last row that are greater than 0. Do you want to count how many are greater than or equal to 0?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas allows you to broadcast comparators, so `df>0` creates a dataframe where each entry is a boolean according to whether the corresponding entry of `df` is greater than `0` (and this also takes care of NaN, since `np.nan > 0` is evaluated as `False`). The `sum` method then coerces `True` to `1` and `False` to `0` and finds the total. Since you want row totals, you want the axis to be `1`. So:

`(df>0).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df.apply(lambda s: (s > 0).sum(), axis=1)
```

Convert it to Boolean and sum it.

Sample Output:

```
  df.apply(lambda s: (s > 1).sum(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  2
  2
  1
  2
dtype: int64
```

You can also use specific column wise condition here, for example:

```
df.apply(lambda s: (s.col1 > 1).sum(), axis=1)
```